# 'SSL Enabled' option is disabled in Visual Studio 2019 Professional

Tags: http, ssl, https, localhost, visual-studio-2019

I'm running my application locally in IISExpress and **'SSL Enabled'** option is greyed out in Visual Studio. I want this to be enabled selected as `'true'` to get the https URL. I've tried number of fixes but nothing works. Any help around this is much appreciated, Thanks.

[image]